# Deploy Java EE application without starting

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, deployment, ear, geronimo

I am using Apache Geronimo.  I need a way to deploy an EAR application on an application server without starting the EAR module automatically.

When I deploy my EAR, it is automatically started. I need a way to specify, that it should only be deployed but not started.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've opened and closed gates to certain EJBs with the use of JMX.

The cool part:

- 100% Control your beans from outside using JConsole or your own JMX client.

The drawback:

- Every bean *instance* has to be registered in the MBean Server which is not that cool as you are usually having multiple instances of the same bean.

The solution to this topic was having a @Singleton EJB working as a MBean/controller for all the instances of one EJB.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your answer. As a casual observer, I haven't learnt how to deploy a JEE app without starting the EAR from your answer